# How get Firebase Device Token like string?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, android-devicetoken

I want to send device Token information when sending membership information to server.

But how should I go because getToken is no longer in use?

I've been using this before:

```
params.put("deviceToken", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
```

Easy and worked but `getToken` is deprecated

```
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("deviceToken", deviceTokenID); <<<---- DEVICE ID TOKEN

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
```

Comment: You have to call getToken first. After it's successful, call the function you need and pass the getToken result.

Comment: `getToken` is deprecated now

Comment: It is. I thought it was already given that `getInstanceId.getId()` is a way to get the token. Same approach. Call to get the token first, then do your function.

Comment: Can I sent notification to user in Firebase with `getInstanceId.getId()` ?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you need to use a success listener like in the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            String tokenId = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            //Do what you need to do with the token
        }
});
```

Comment: I've seen your shared code on many websites but I can't use it. How can I add this into `params.put`? I can't do because my Java knowledge is not good

Comment: Your question is: "How get Firebase Device Token like string?" at which I have already provided an answer. This is another problem which is beyond the scope of this question. Please ask another question that explains the problem, and what you've tried already to solve it, so me and other users can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String deviceToken= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
 params.put("deviceToken", deviceToken);
```

Comment: Add some explanation

Comment: `getToken` is deprecated now